# Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend > didn't respond within 10 seconds

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore is working fine for me unless I recompile my Angular code (hosting locally, using chrome) wait a while and then go to the browser tab where the app is.  I then have the error below.  If I then refresh the page it works fine.

However if I recompile my code and then immediately go to the page then it works.  Basically unless I am actively on the tab when it loads it has this error.

Any ideas why?

Have tried turning of virus checker and firewall.  Thinking maybe it is a browser thing.

> Firestore (7.23.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend
> didn't respond within 10 seconds. This typically indicates that your
> device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The
> client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully
> connect to the backend.

Comment: Have you seen this GitHub [open issue link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/901)?

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo Thanks.  I have commented in there.  Looks like a common issue.  Its just started in the last 2 weeks for me.  Fine before that.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the new chrome background tab throttling.

[https://chromeunboxed.com/whats-new-chrome-desktop-86#:~:text=In%20the%20past%2C%20your%20browser,once%20you%20click%20on%20them](https://chromeunboxed.com/whats-new-chrome-desktop-86#:%7E:text=In%20the%20past%2C%20your%20browser,once%20you%20click%20on%20them).

**I just switched to using Firefox and I no longer have the problem.**

Goodbye Chrome for development.

I am a bit concerned about what happens to end users in production though. I will need to test that.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.  https://winaero.com/disable-tab-throttling-google-chrome/